# Dell 4400 DisplayPort sound problem

Tags: hdmi

I've a Dell M4400 laptop and am using a DisplayPort to HDMI cable, but the sound just plays out of the speakers - not out of the attached TV. 
Does the DisplayPort support audio? Do I need a driver or something to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

I spotted one [forum post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Displayport-to-HDMI-with-audio/m-p/68575/page/13) about this that indicates that yes, audio pass-thru is possible on the M4400:

> It may be necessary to open the Sound Control Panel and set Digital Output Device (SPDIF) to Default. It may also be necessary to restart your media player application to reflect the change.

You may need to disable the use of the laptop's speakers in the same control panel.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this when I'm at that computer again.